# Can all algorithms be described as O(1)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I read that the formal definition of Big O notation is:

T(n) is considered O(f(n)) if there exist a constant c and n0 where T(n) <= c.f(n)+n0 for all n > n0.

But I was wondering, doesn't that mean that if an algorithm is O(n), it must also be O(n^2) and O(n^3) etc?

For surely if there exist a constant c and n0 where T(n) <= c.n+n0 for all n > n0. There must also be a constant c and n0 where T(n) <= c.(n^2)+n0 for all n > n0.

In fact, every algorithm can be said to have O(1) if you choose c = infinity, because any T(n) will be <= infinity.1+n0.

I know this completely defeats the purpose of Big O notations. But I was wondering where I'm going wrong, and what I'm missing.

Comment: c=infinity is not a valid choice of c. We're working in the real numbers, or perhaps the integers or naturals. None of those systems includes an infinity.

Comment: @user2357112 ah I see. What about the case of multiple O(f(n))? can a function be O(log n) and O(n) and O(n^2)? With different c and n0 for each of course.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36289/is-infinity-a-number may be useful in understanding how "Infinity is not a number".

Comment: @Synia: Yup. You might also want to look at related notations, particularly Big-Theta, which is more restrictive.

Comment: The thing about the order of a function is that it is the least upper bound. If you have an O(n) function it is also O(n^2) and also O(e^n), but n is the least upper bound. "There exists c, n0 s.t. T(n) <= c.n+n0 for all n > n0" implies "There exists c, n0 s.t. T(n) <= c.(n^2)+n0 for all n > n0" holds, but you can't say the reverse. The definition of an order of a function also requires that c is a constant number, which infinity is not.

Comment: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/269676/how-does-big-o-notation-indicate-upper-bound-on-a-function may also be useful for another question on big O.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FunctionOrder.html

Comment: @user2357112 no plans to change your name?

Comment: @MidTwo: No plans. I like the 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 sequence that ended up in my autogenerated name. It might be nice to be more recognizable, but I don't really have a strong desire for that.

Answer (score 1):

O(n) is a *set* of functions, and when we say "T(n) is O(n)" or even "T(n) = O(n)", we are just being sloppy and should more correctly say "T(n) *is in* O(n)".

As you have determined, O(n^2) is a superset of O(n), and O(n^3) is a superset of O(n^2), so if T(n) is in O(n), then it is also in O(n^2) and O(n^3).

The second part you have wrong, though:  infinity is not a real number, so you can't use it as a constant and deduce that everything is in O(1).